# Find all possible combinations of array without permutations

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, combinations, permutation

Input is an array of 'n' length.
I need all combinations inside this array stored into new array.

```
IN: j='{A, B, C ..}'
OUT: k='{A, B, C, AB, AC, BC, ABC ..}'
```

Without repetitions, so without `BA`, `CA` etc.

Comment: Homework project? (It's OK if so, just best to say explicitly).

Comment: The second term you were looking for is ["permutation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Generic solution using a [recursive CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html)

Works for **any number of elements** and **any base data type** that supports the `>` operator.

```
WITH RECURSIVE t(i) AS (SELECT * FROM unnest('{A,B,C}'::text[]))  -- provide array
, cte AS (
   SELECT i::text AS combo, i, 1 AS ct
   FROM   t
  
   UNION  ALL
   SELECT cte.combo || t.i::text, t.i, ct + 1
   FROM   cte
   JOIN   t ON t.i > cte.i
   )
SELECT ARRAY (   
   SELECT combo
   FROM   cte
   ORDER  BY ct, combo
   ) AS result;
```

Result is an array of `text` in the example.

Note that you can have any number of additional non-recursive CTEs when using the `RECURSIVE` keyword.

#### More generic yet

If any of the following apply:

- Array elements are non-unique (like `'{A,B,B}'`).
- The base data type does not support the `>` operator (like `json`).
- Array elements are very big - for better performance.

Use a row number instead of comparing elements:

```
WITH RECURSIVE t AS (
   SELECT i::text, row_number() OVER () AS rn
   FROM   unnest('{A,B,B}'::text[]) i         -- duplicate element!
   )
, cte AS (
   SELECT i AS combo, rn, 1 AS ct
   FROM   t
  
   UNION  ALL
   SELECT cte.combo || t.i, t.rn, ct + 1
   FROM   cte
   JOIN   t ON t.rn > cte.rn
   )
SELECT ARRAY (   
   SELECT combo
   FROM   cte
   ORDER  BY ct, combo
   ) AS result;
```

Or use `WITH ORDINALITY` in Postgres 9.4+:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

#### Special case: generate decimal numbers

To generate decimal numbers with 5 digits along these lines:

```
WITH RECURSIVE t AS (
   SELECT i
   FROM   unnest('{1,2,3,4,5}'::int[]) i
   )
, cte AS (
   SELECT i AS nr, i
   FROM   t
  
   UNION  ALL
   SELECT cte.nr * 10 + t.i, t.i
   FROM   cte
   JOIN   t ON t.i > cte.i
   )
SELECT ARRAY (   
   SELECT nr
   FROM   cte
   ORDER  BY nr
   ) AS result;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb/450) demonstrating all.

Answer (score 1):

if n is small < 20 , all possible combinations can be found using a bitmask approach. There are 2^n different combinations of it. The number values 0 to 
(2^n - 1) represents one of the combination.
e.g n=3

0 represents {},empty element
2^3-1=7= 111 b represents element, abc

pseudo code as follows

```
for b=0 to 2^n - 1 do #each combination
  res=""
  for i=0 to (n-1) do   # which elements are included

     if (b && (1<<i) != 0)
        res= res+arr[i]
    end
    print res
  end
end
```